# How to create a LaTeX class with default parameters?

Tags: latex

I've learnt how to use LaTeX at the user level, but wanted to package the recurring code (resulting mostly from the styling of the cover) in a class file. 
Therefore, I tried the following simple example class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2018/10/12 v0.1 Test class]
\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{report}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClassWithOptions{report}
```

Although this works if I pass the size I want, if I omit it, it defaults to 10pt, instead of 12pt that I want. Do you know how to make the default become the 12pt, and still work if I decide to give it another size option?

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123623/36296 you could so something like

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2018/10/12 v0.1 Test class]

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\test@ptsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\test@ptsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\test@ptsize{12pt}}

\ExecuteOptions{12pt}
\ProcessOptions
\PassOptionsToClass{\test@ptsize}{report}

\LoadClass{report}

\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{test}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```